# Can we connect to resources in other subnets in same vnet using a azure private endpoint?

Tags: azure-virtual-network, azure-redis-cache, azure-private-link

Can we connect to resources in other subnets in same vnet using an azure private endpoint?

I have three subnets subnet-A, subnet-B, and subnet-C in the same VNET test vnet.

If I created a private endpoint for azure Redis service with subnet-A, will resources in this subnet as well as in other subnets be able to connect to my Redis instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can we connect to resources in other subnets in same vnet using an
> azure private endpoint?

By default when the Azure resources are present inside a VNET , then they can communicate with each other privately. You can refer this ***[`Microsoft Documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-overview#communicate-between-azure-resources)*** for more details on ***Virtual Network***.

> If I created a private endpoint for azure Redis service with subnet-A,
> will resources in this subnet as well as in other subnets be able to
> connect to my Redis instance?

Yes, other resources can communicate with Redis Cache even if it is configured with private endpoint as both of the resources will have Azure Network as Backbone. You can refer this ***[`Microsoft Documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-link-overview?toc=/azure/virtual-network/toc.json#key-benefits)*** for more details on ***Private Link***.

Answer (score 3):

Yes any resource can connect to the private end point as long as they are with in the same VNET. Does not matter if they are in the same or different subnet.
Adding to that , resources from other VNETS can also connect to the private end point if there is a VNET peering between the source and target vnets.

Comment: You could link to documentation to make the answer stand on its own legs and be more complete.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, taking this a step ahead, if the same scenario of this question required use of Service Endpoints, I assume each subnet would need to create one(cannot have single service endpoint used across subnets in the vnet)?